# Backbone.js / Marionette - Updating region triggers infinite loop, page refresh

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm not entirely certain what is happening here. I have a module, that is responsible for displaying the navigation in a region on my page. For whatever reason, when I trigger the display (`Manager.trigger("navigation:show");`) the entire page refreshes, and continues to refresh ad infinitum.

I've been staring at this for a while trying to track down exactly what is going on, but figure it best I step away for a moment. I assume there is some recursion occurring somewhere, but thus far I haven't been able to track it down.

**navigation_app.js**

```
Manager.module("NavigationApp", function(NavigationApp, Manager, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
    NavigationApp.Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
        appRoutes: {
        }
    });

    var API = {
        showNavigation: function() {
            NavigationApp.Show.Controller.showNavigation();
        },
    };

    Manager.on("navigation:show", function() {
        API.showNavigation();
    });

    Manager.addInitializer(function() {
        new NavigationApp.Router({
            controller: API
        });
    });
});
```

**navigation_controller.js**

```
Manager.module("NavigationApp.Show", function(Show, Manager, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
    Show.Controller = {
        showNavigation: function() {    
            console.log("showNavigation() called");
            var navigation = Manager.request("navigation:entities");

            var navigationView = new Manager.NavigationApp.Show.NavigationView({
                collection: navigation
            }); 

            Manager.navigationRegion.show(navigationView);
        }
    }
});
```

**navigation_view.js**

```
Manager.module("NavigationApp.Show", function(Show, Manager, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
    Show.NavigationItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: "#navigation-item-view",

        events: {
        },
    });

    Show.NavigationView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        template: "#navigation-view",
        itemView: Show.NavigationItemView,
    });
});
```

**Callstack** (This just repeats, the page reloads, and it repeats again)

```
x.Callbacks.c
x.Callbacks.p.fireWith
k
x.ajaxTransport.send.r
x.ajaxTransport.send
x.extend.ajax
x.extend._evalUrl
x.fn.extend.domManip
x.fn.extend.append
c.extend.open
c.extend.show
Show.Controller.showNavigation
```

Comment: Do you have the stack trace where the recursion happens? I think Chrome does show that sometimes

Comment: @TanNguyen See the edit I made. The problem is, it's a recursion in the sense that it loads the page again, and that triggers whatever loaded the page last time to refresh the entire page. If I comment out the `Manager.navigationRegion.show(navigationView);` it recurse infinitely (but also doesn't display).

Comment: Not sure if I miss it or what but I don't see anywhere in your code that does `ajax` call?

Comment: @TanNguyen I don't, but I presumed it may be part of the internals of backbone.js or something.

Comment: I doubt that. Anyways, I think you should check what the ajax call actually does (what it calls to). Because your recursion happens around the callback of the ajax call, so it's worth checking it out